# need to implement translation in child module angular 8 BaseComponent is abstract class and LanguageTranslateService is Translation service

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to implement Translation in Angular 8 Application.

Translation successfully implemented in all components but when I am trying to implement on child component it show error:

> undefined

Code of App.module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardModule } from './dashboard/dashboard.module';
import { LayoutModule } from './layout/layout.module';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { SharedServicesService } from './SharedServices/shared-services.service';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { CommonModalsComponent } from './common-modals/common-modals.component';
import { DefineGroupModule } from './define-group/define-group.module';
import { MaterialModuleModule } from './material-module/material-module.module';
import { DefineGroupModalComponent } from './define-group/define-group-modal/define-group-modal.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    ConfirmDialogComponent,
    CommonModalsComponent,
    CustomConfirmModalsComponent,
    DefineGroupModalComponent,
    NewUserPopUpComponent,
    AddNewControllComponent,
    AddEscalationComponent ,
    NumberOnlyDirective
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    DashboardModule,
    DefineGroupModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    LayoutModule,
    DashboardModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule,
    HttpClientModule
    ],
  providers: [SharedServicesService,
    LanguageTranslateService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [DefineGroupModalComponent, NewUserPopUpComponent,   
    ConfirmDialogComponent, CommonModalsComponent, CustomConfirmModalsComponent,
    AddNewControllComponent, AddEscalationComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Code for Parent component

```
export class DefineGroupComponent extends BaseComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public languageTranslateService: LanguageTranslateService,
              private _svc: SharedServicesService, public dialog: MatDialog,
              private GlobalVariableService: GlobalVariableService) {
    super(languageTranslateService);
   }
```

Code In HTML

```
  <div class="col-sm">
    <button color="primary" class="ctgrySaveButton pull-right" mat-raised-button
     name='SaveDefineGroup' (click)="NewEdit('New')">
         {{langObject.DefineNewGroup}}
    </button>
  </div>
```

I have written same code for child component but as child component has no module and is directly called its component in app module it is not getting the `languageTranslateService`.

Comment: what do you mean it has no module? every component should be declared in some module

Comment: Child components or popup are directly declared in entryComponents in app.Modules

Comment: did you try adding them to "declarations" as well?

Comment: child components have not module these are popup modals or dialogue child are woking fine expect translation service

Comment: @DPro sir any help plz